# Different settings for each application with Django

Tags: django, settings

How do I use different setting for each application?

For example:

- http://www.mysite.com/app1 uses the settings.py + local_settings.py of the app1's folder...
- http://www.mysite.com/app2 uses the settings.py + local_settings.py of the app2's folder...

etc...

Thanks,

Comment: Just curious, what settings do you need to be different between the apps?

Answer (score 4):

you could check all ways of splitting up your settings from here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings

Answer (score 1):

Older relevant thread talking about per application settings:

http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/fc8b2e284459f6cf

You can run multiple django instances on a single domain with different settings using the advice from here:

[multiple instances of django on a single domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232349/multiple-instances-of-django-on-a-single-domain)

Answer (score -1):

It's not pretty, but you can put the following in your `settings.py` after `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
for app in INSTALLED_APPS:
    local_settings = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, app, 'local_settings.py')
    if os.path.isfile(local_settings):
        execfile(local_settings)
```

Comment: Doesn't this load all the local_settings instead of allowing for different settings for each app?

Comment: Note- You wouldn't be able to have different namespaces for each app.  Duplicate settings for each app would override eachother.

Comment: I don't know if it would be possible to have different settings for each app.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this load all the settings... I want to load only the right settings file!