# Django - application specific middleware

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-middleware

I am aware of the following methods for adding middlewares
1) Adding custom middleware component to django using [MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     '......'
    'path.to.custom.middlware',)
```

2) Adding view specific middleware using [decorate_from_middlware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware)

```
cache_page = decorator_from_middleware(CacheMiddleware)

@cache_page(3600)
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

My request is how to create application specific middleware class like

```
APPSPECIFIC_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 'path.to.middlwareclass1',
 'path.to.middlwareclass2',
 'path.to.middlwareclass3', )
```

middlwareclass is either function or class ? 
Is there any to do this using url or any other method,. Or 2nd method is the only way and to add all middleware classes separately to the view ?

Update : 
http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html
As in the about application, the SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE is working for the social app alone. which differs from the global project settings..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Refer this, May be it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-setup-custom-middleware-in-django

Comment: @user2393267  As I requested it should be application specific. If I add the middleware it will be applicable for all applications in django project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django settings per application - best practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386580/django-settings-per-application-best-practice)

Answer (score 6):

This is probably not possible in way that you want it, because django does not track what view comes from what application. But you can create some middleware with condition inside `process_view`, you can check here what view is being called and do something if view is matching your criteria (in that case, view comes from particular app).

Another approach, if you're using class-based views is to create some view mixin or base view in your application, decorate it with your middleware and use it in each view from your application.

Comment: In this http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html the pipelines are made specific to particular(social) app. However now I will include the conditions in process_view .. @GwynBleidD thanks :)