# Django - accessing app settings in another app

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django so this might be a basic question but I am not able to find how to implement it.

So I have an app in my Django project, lets call it `player`. In the `apps.py` I want to add some settings that are specific to this app. So the code is like:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PlayerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'player'
    player_key = 'GJHGJGJJKJK'
```

Now I have another app named `engine`. This has a `serializer.py` in which I want to create to create a player_engine and pass the `player.player_key` to it.

so my serializer has a piece of code that looks like this:

```
from engines import player_engine

class EngineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
   # some meta configuration values here
   ...

   def validate(self, data)
       player_engine = PlayerEngine(player.player_key)
       #in above method, I want to know to pass player.player_key
       ...
```

I know there might be better way to structure this etc, however this is a legacy Django implementation and I cannot restructure things, so I would really appreciate if anyone can point me to a solution keeping this structure intact.

Ideally I want to know if there is way app level settings can somehow be clubbed into the settings available in django's settings.py

Comment: Haven't tried it, but perhaps: `from django.apps import apps; apps.get_app_config('player').player_key`

Comment: @thebjorn - unfortunately it did not work. Seems like I only update a predefined set of attributes in a subclass of AppConfig :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use [django-zero-settings](https://github.com/aasmpro/django-zero-settings), which may help you in some cases. checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68916822/6484831