# Django root site in virtual directory

Tags: django, urlconf

The following is the setup:

- I have a virtual directory in IIS 6 in which my Django app lives, IIS is configured to pass every request on that virtual directory to the Django WSGI handler

  Let's say this is domain.com/virtual/
- In my Django dev URL CONF I had urls configured like this: `url( r'^home$, 'project.views.home' )`

**Question**:

Is there an easy way (through Django settings OR server settings) to set some kind of ROOT_URL for the django app? (Without manually prepending as this is incompatbile with i18n_patterns)

Django should treat all patterns as rooted in the ROOT_URL and redirect - again - relative to that same ROOT URL.

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple instances of django on a single domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232349/multiple-instances-of-django-on-a-single-domain)

Comment: The solution presented there is pretty much "prepend the virtual directory to every possible pattern". But this does not work for me since i18n_patterns prepends the language code to patterns, thus going outside the root URL

Comment: I might have been a bit quick to pull the duplicate trigger, but AFAIK, there is no way to support 'application names'. Can you not have the django at the root url?

Comment: Instead of deploying to a virtual directory, can you deploy it as a Site?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past.

In your settings file add a setting called something like:
VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY = "your_virtual_directory/"

If you are doing dev or have this behind it's own site domain you can keep it blank.

Then in your site's urls.py file add this to all of your top level url patterns:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'%sadmin' % settings.VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY),
)
```

Do the string pattern for all of your url patterns.  You will only need to do this at the site level urls.py not for every app. This way if you have a non blank VIRTUAL_DIRECTORY then it will prefix it to all of your top level url patterns.